# How to set path to file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have located file in root directory of Laravel.

From controller I try to get this file like as:

```
$shipments = json_decode(file_get_contents("Statistics.json"), true);
```

But I get error.

What correct path to specify for getting file?

Comment: To get the root path use base_path(); function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths

I guess you need  `base_path`

```
file_get_contents(base_path().'/Statistics.json');
```